# Boostrap 4 Beta Pagination in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I'm making a web app with CodeIniter and `Bootstrap` 4 Beta. I am stuck on integrating `bootstrap` 4 style on CodeIgniter pagination $config

How can I properly integrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter makes it extremely easy to output HTML to match what bootstrap 4 styles:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

// This is how you match BASIC bootstrap 4 styles for pagination
$pagination_config = array(
    'first_tag_open'  => '<li class="page-item">',
    'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
    'last_tag_open'   => '<li class="page-item">',
    'last_tag_close'  => '</li>',
    'next_tag_open'   => '<li class="page-item">',
    'next_tag_close'  => '</li>',
    'prev_tag_open'   => '<li class="page-item">',
    'prev_tag_close'  => '</li>',
    'cur_tag_open'    => '<li class="page-item active">',
    'cur_tag_close'   => '</li>',
    'num_tag_open'    => '<li class="page-item">',
    'num_tag_close'   => '</li>'    
);

// Example of how to add any other pagination configuration ...
$pagination_config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$pagination_config['total_rows'] = 200;
$pagination_config['per_page'] = 20;

// Initialize the pagination
$this->pagination->initialize($pagination_config);
```

When you output the pagination in your view, you'll use something like this:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you would read the CodeIgniter user guide, it would be extremely beneficial to your success.